# Inserting data into one table then multiple rows into another using data from the first using stored procedures (SQL + C#)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Ok so I am new here :) I am relatively new to SQL, and I am trying to insert data into multiple tables. I have both inserts to work however I want it so if one fails neither are committed.
The tables look like this:

Student -
StudentID - int PK,
StudentName - Varchar,
etc ...

Class -
ClassID - int PK,
ClassName - varchar,
etc...

StudentClass - 
StudentID,
ClassID,

What I am trying to do is create a new Student whom can belong to multiple classes. So I have created the Student class table to break up the many-many relationship. I have a stored procedure to insert a new student and return the newest StudentID and then I use this StudentID, in a new stored procedure, and a table value parameter to insert multiple rows into StudentClass table. These are the stored procedures:

Create A Student:

```
@FirstName varchar(20) = '', 
@LastName varchar(20) = '',
@PredictedGrade char(1) = '',
@ActionPlan bit = 0,
@StudentActive bit = 1,
@StudentID int out

INSERT INTO Student (FirstName, LastName, PredictedGrade, ActionPlan, StudentActive)
VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @PredictedGrade, @ActionPlan, @StudentActive)
SET @StudentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Add Multiple Rows To StudentClass Table:

```
(@StudentClassCollection As InsertStudentClass READONLY)

INSERT INTO StudentClass(StudentID, ClassID)
SELECT StudentID, ClassID FROM @StudentClassCollection
```

So both of these work however I don't know how to make it so if one fails the other will not execute and changes will not be committed? So effectively I need to perform both actions one after the other in the same stored procedure? I think! As I said I am new so if I have done anything wrong please let me know I will correct it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like the below

```
using (SqlConnection  connection= new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
   {
     connection.Open();
     SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
     try
     {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("proc1",connection);
        //execute the above command
        command.CommandText="proc2";
        //execute command again for proc2
        transaction.Commit();                   
     }
     catch
     {
       //Roll back the transaction.
       transaction.Rollback();
     }  
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like the best way as I can continue to use my existing stored procedures :) I would have voted but I can' yet!

Answer (score 1):

[In case of an error, rollback will be issued automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

begin transaction

-- YOUR WORK HERE

commit transaction
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know about XACT_ABORT I'm sure it will be useful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
begin tran

// all insert , update script here    


IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK tran
END
ELSE
    commit tran
```